# Accessing process.env with Vite in VueJS 2

Tags: npm, vuejs2, vue-component, vite

I'm in the process of converting an existing Vue-2 project to Vite with `@vitejs/plugin-vue2`

Now i have the problem that `process.env` is not  defined. Yes i know, i have to use `import.meta.env` and that works. But there are some Third-Party-Components that are using `process.env`

For example https://vuelidate.js.org/#getting-started

It is possible to use `process.env` in a Vite-Environment?

Comment: upgrade to Vuelidate 2.  It supports both Vue 3 and Vue 2.x and should work with vite.  If that is somehow not feasible for your app, there is a [workaround](https://github.com/vuelidate/vuelidate/issues/1109#issuecomment-1248547838) you can try

Answer (score 0):

The node version you are running is causing that issue, you may need to downgrade the version of node js you are running.